# matplotlib show() suspends ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, matplotlib

I've written a python script to plot a cross-section from a DEM along a line.

Everything works fine except when I Show the plot, ArcGIS hangs and I have to force it to close with Task Manager.

I am working with Windows 7 and ArcGIS 10.3. Following is my code snippet:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
...
...
plt.plot(x,y) 
plt.xlabel('Distance (m)') 
plt.ylabel('Elevation (m)') 
plt.title('X-section along the line') 
plt.grid(True) 
plt.savefig('Xsection.png') 
plt.show() 
plt.close()
```

Comment: matplotlib uses tkinter by default, which ESRI does not support using from within ArcGIS. It may be possible to use PyQT instead, but I've never done it.

Comment: I believe the problem is actually related to the trying to save the figure. Try using the full path to the figure when saving. Otherwise I had no issues with any of these plt calls.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "ArcGIS hangs"?  If you are trying to run this within ArcMap then I think what @EvilGenius says is probably right i.e. that you are up against a tkinter / ArcGIS integration issue.  There are a number of Q&As on this site about those.